# hibernate @CollectionOfElements not persisted

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

HI,

I am using Hibernate with plenty of satisfaction so far. Lately it seems that I am not able to persist a @CollectionOfElements using annotation.

I am saving an object of class Estate which contains a Map of RoomGroups like here:

```
@javax.persistence.MapKey(name = "code")
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "estate")
@org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy(clause = "code ASC")
private Map<String, RoomsGroup> roomGroups = new HashMap<String, RoomsGroup>();
```

The RoomGroup is persisted correctly. And RoomGroup has also the relationship with MasterPrice

```
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "roomGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private MasterPrice prices;
```

So far so good, MasterPrice elements are correctly stored in DB. Now inside MasterPrice there is another collection and this one seems that is never going to be persisted

```
@CollectionOfElements (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
  name = "roomgroups_masterprice_items",
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_masterpricesID")})
@IndexColumn(name = "position")
private List<MasterPriceItem> dbprices = new ArrayList<MasterPriceItem>();
```

The class MasterPriceItem is defined like this

```
@Embeddable
public class MasterPriceItem implements Serializable{
```

I defined also the equal/hashCode methods in the MasterPriceItem but it seems that hibernate is never persisting this one. I do not get any exception and when I try to load it always comes up as NULL.

I am using hibernate_3.3.1.ga any idea that I can try? The class MasterPriceItem is correctly analysed by hibernate [if I put a field that is not in the table, I get an error]

Any help highly appreciated. thx.